# ld output not repeatable because of symbol order in symbol table

Tags: macos, ld

I thought it would be a good idea to validate my build process by building from my exported source archive and comparing the output to my exported binary output. But I ran into a nasty problem. When I build a shared library, I don't always get the same output. I tried running the build script four times in a row, and got two different output files - in the order #1, #2, #2, #1. (I think this order should demonstrate that it is not an issue of failing to do clean builds.) The only differences in the output files are the order in which external symbols appear in the symbol table. The `ld` command lines are the same except for the name of the temporary directory created by `cc`.

What could be causing this behavior?

My environment is OS X 10.10.5.

Here is an example of the differences found by diff-ing the output of `otool`. (There are actually two sets of similar differences.)

```
556,598c556,598

< 0x0000000000006e6a   199 _objc_begin_catch
< 0x0000000000006e70   200 _objc_end_catch
< 0x0000000000006e76   201 _objc_exception_rethrow
< 0x0000000000006e7c   202 _objc_msgSend
< 0x0000000000006e82   203 _objc_msgSend_stret
< 0x0000000000006e88   204 _objc_terminate
< 0x0000000000006e8e   102 _CFArrayGetCount
< 0x0000000000006e94   103 _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
< 0x0000000000006e9a   104 _CFBundleCreate
< 0x0000000000006ea0   105 _CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName
< 0x0000000000006ea6   106 _CFDataCreate
< 0x0000000000006eac   107 _CFDateGetAbsoluteTime
< 0x0000000000006eb2   108 _CFNumberGetValue
< 0x0000000000006eb8   109 _CFRelease
< 0x0000000000006ebe   110 _CFRetain
< 0x0000000000006ec4   111 _CFStringCreateWithCharacters
< 0x0000000000006eca   112 _CFStringGetCharacters
< 0x0000000000006ed0   113 _CFStringGetLength
< 0x0000000000006ed6   114 _CFURLCopyFileSystemPath
< 0x0000000000006edc   115 _CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey
< 0x0000000000006ee2   116 _CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromAliasRecord
< 0x0000000000006ee8   117 _CFURLCreateByResolvingBookmarkData
< 0x0000000000006eee   118 _CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation
< 0x0000000000006ef4   119 _CGBitmapContextCreate
< 0x0000000000006efa   120 _CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB
< 0x0000000000006f00   121 _CGColorSpaceRelease
< 0x0000000000006f06   122 _CGContextRelease
< 0x0000000000006f0c   132 _LSCopyItemInfoForURL
< 0x0000000000006f12   133 _LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot
< 0x0000000000006f18   134 _LSSharedFileListCreate
< 0x0000000000006f1e   135 _LSSharedFileListGetSeedValue
< 0x0000000000006f24   136 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName
< 0x0000000000006f2a   137 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyIconRef
< 0x0000000000006f30   138 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyProperty
< 0x0000000000006f36   139 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyResolvedURL
< 0x0000000000006f3c   140 _LSSharedFileListItemGetID
< 0x0000000000006f42   141 _MDItemCopyAttribute
< 0x0000000000006f48   142 _MDItemCreateWithURL
< 0x0000000000006f4e   143 _MDQueryCreate
< 0x0000000000006f54   144 _MDQueryExecute
< 0x0000000000006f5a   145 _MDQueryGetResultAtIndex
< 0x0000000000006f60   146 _MDQueryGetResultCount
< 0x0000000000006f66   147 _MDQuerySetSearchScope
---
> 0x0000000000006e6a   119 _CGBitmapContextCreate
> 0x0000000000006e70   120 _CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB
> 0x0000000000006e76   121 _CGColorSpaceRelease
> 0x0000000000006e7c   122 _CGContextRelease
> 0x0000000000006e82   132 _LSCopyItemInfoForURL
> 0x0000000000006e88   133 _LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot
> 0x0000000000006e8e   134 _LSSharedFileListCreate
> 0x0000000000006e94   135 _LSSharedFileListGetSeedValue
> 0x0000000000006e9a   136 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName
> 0x0000000000006ea0   137 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyIconRef
> 0x0000000000006ea6   138 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyProperty
> 0x0000000000006eac   139 _LSSharedFileListItemCopyResolvedURL
> 0x0000000000006eb2   140 _LSSharedFileListItemGetID
> 0x0000000000006eb8   141 _MDItemCopyAttribute
> 0x0000000000006ebe   142 _MDItemCreateWithURL
> 0x0000000000006ec4   143 _MDQueryCreate
> 0x0000000000006eca   144 _MDQueryExecute
> 0x0000000000006ed0   145 _MDQueryGetResultAtIndex
> 0x0000000000006ed6   146 _MDQueryGetResultCount
> 0x0000000000006edc   147 _MDQuerySetSearchScope
> 0x0000000000006ee2   199 _objc_begin_catch
> 0x0000000000006ee8   200 _objc_end_catch
> 0x0000000000006eee   201 _objc_exception_rethrow
> 0x0000000000006ef4   202 _objc_msgSend
> 0x0000000000006efa   203 _objc_msgSend_stret
> 0x0000000000006f00   204 _objc_terminate
> 0x0000000000006f06   102 _CFArrayGetCount
> 0x0000000000006f0c   103 _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
> 0x0000000000006f12   104 _CFBundleCreate
> 0x0000000000006f18   105 _CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName
> 0x0000000000006f1e   106 _CFDataCreate
> 0x0000000000006f24   107 _CFDateGetAbsoluteTime
> 0x0000000000006f2a   108 _CFNumberGetValue
> 0x0000000000006f30   109 _CFRelease
> 0x0000000000006f36   110 _CFRetain
> 0x0000000000006f3c   111 _CFStringCreateWithCharacters
> 0x0000000000006f42   112 _CFStringGetCharacters
> 0x0000000000006f48   113 _CFStringGetLength
> 0x0000000000006f4e   114 _CFURLCopyFileSystemPath
> 0x0000000000006f54   115 _CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey
> 0x0000000000006f5a   116 _CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromAliasRecord
> 0x0000000000006f60   117 _CFURLCreateByResolvingBookmarkData
> 0x0000000000006f66   118 _CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation
```